# Delaying a Jquery function until Ajax is completely loaded

Tags: jquery-plugins, rss, jquery

I am using a [plugin](http://www.rssreader.clashdesign.be/) that uses jquery to pull an rss feed, and displays it after the content loads. I wanted to use [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html) so I can have custom scrollbars.

WithjScrollPane, it loads the scrollbars on pageload, but because  the rssreader loads content with ajax, the scrollbars aren't applied (it takes 4 seconds to load the rss content, and by that time, the scrollbars have already tried loading. Because no content was there, they dont appear). I need to use jquery to tell jscrollpane not to load the scrollbars until the rss is fully loaded. You can view the page [here](http://www.vitaminjdesign.com/fsa/indexnew.html).

As you can see in the bottom left, the content is loaded, but doesn't display a scrollbar. I need a simple jquery command that says" do not run the jscrollpane commands until after the rss feed is fully loaded." Any ideas?

Comment: There is no callback function on the rss feed (i think), so how would I go about adding one to the existing code here:  http://vitaminjdesign.com/rss/jquery.rssreader-0.2.pack.js

Comment: couldnt i delay the loading of the scrollbar by 6 seconds? Its dirty, but it will work (assuming the rss loads in that timeframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a callback function on the rss feed plugin and apply the scoll bars plugin in it. If the rss feed plugin does not allow you to specify a callback function, you'll need to edit the code to add one.

Answer (score 0):

if there is not a callback available on the rssfeed plugin you can use  setTimeout  checking until div newsfeed got some content from rssfeed . Then call jScroll and stop the timer . not an elegant solution but works